# First to Default

Tags: quantitative, credit

Hi I would like a clarification on how to price a first to default over a basket of two names with correlation rho=0.2 via Li Model using Gaussian Copula.
Up to now I've tried to extract a gaussian sample and correlate it via a linear transformation. But I still have issues on the rate to use on the fee leg when pricing.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use [David X. Li's Gaussian copula]( doi:10.3905/jfi.2000.319253) to price $n$th to default baskets? You may want to read https://www.wired.com/2009/02/wp-quant/ , https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB112649094075137685 first :)

Comment: I know about that but it's required by the assignment and it's one of the criticalities we want to highlight